# Error saying symbol not found

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
 if(packageInput.equals(A))
     hoursA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of hours used:");

    rateA=Integer.parseInt(hoursA); 

  if(rateA > 10)
{
  optionA=(rateA - 10) * 2.00 + 9.95; 

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total bill for the month is $ "          
                                                           + optionA);}

  else
  {
     rateA=Integer.parseInt(hoursA);

     optionA=(rateA*0) + 9.95
     JOptionPane.showMessaageDialog(null, "The total bill for the month is $ " 
                                                                 + optionA);}
```

I do not know what to do in order to get this bit to work I keep getting a cannot find symbol error and to me that doesn't make sense because I am already using the JOptionPane earlier in the program and no errors there.

```
java:47: error: cannot find symbol
         JOptionPane.showMessaageDialog(null, "The total bill for the month is $ " 
                    ^
  symbol:   method showMessaageDialog(<null>,String)
  location: class JOptionPane
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated and explain so I can learn not to do this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

```
if(packageInput.equals(A))
    hoursA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of hours used:");
rateA=Integer.parseInt(hoursA);
```

If the `if` condition is false then `hoursA` will be uninitialized.  If you intended both statements to be in the `if` statement's `true` branch, put braces around both, as in

```
if(packageInput.equals(A)) {
    hoursA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of hours used:");
    rateA=Integer.parseInt(hoursA); 
}
```

However, realize that both `hoursA` and `rateA` will remain unitialized if the `if` condition is false and you'll get the same error in later code if it refers to either variable.

```
JOptionPane.showMessaageDialog
```

`showMessageDialog` is mis-spelled. It has two `a` characters when it should have only one.

Comment: Even with the else statement? Or should I put an else statement for that for the other options (B, C).